# How to install Linux VM on Microsoft Hyper-V

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hyper-v

**I am looking for step-by-step guide to do so.** I can go for any easy to work with Linux distribution , may be UBUNTU.

But Hyper-V page says it officially supports only SUSE and REDHAT, others can be done on owner's risk.

I dont need future compatibility etc as yet, just need to do some experiments, so any distribution would be fine.

FYI - I am trying BOINC installation and testing.

Answer (score 0):

This only means it is what MS supports if you call and have a problem. Install it as you would on any virtualization platform. Be aware that the remote management console will not work properly if you are running an XWindows session. So managing it from a say Win 7 client machine would be a PITA. I would just use SSH, though, with no XWindows.